# In a Hilbert space, $\lim_\limits{n\to ∞} |(x, e_n)| = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let ${e_n}$ be an orthornormal basis in a Hilbert space $H$ and let $x \in H$. Prove that we
always have $\lim_{n\to \infty} |(x, e_n)| = 0$.

Proof Idea:

How can this be right? If $x=\sum c_ke_k$ since $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis,

then $|(x, e_n)| =|c_k|$. How can the limit be $0$?

Comment: Yes, there is mistake, because $|(x, e_n)| = |c_n|$

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. So $lim |(x, e_n)| = lim |c_n|$. Still, how can this be 0 as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Use Bessel's inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does actually mean $x = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n e_n$ for separable Hilbert space $H$ with basis $e_n$? This means, that if increase $n$ we go closer and closer to $x$, and since all Hilbert spaces must be complete by definition, by taking the limit we get exactly $x$. Strickly this means the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i e_i = x  \implies | x -  \sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i e_i| \to_{n \to \infty} 0 
$$
This was just the lyrics about *how we can think about the elements of Hilbert space with basis $e_n$*, but it helps in some sence intuitively understand why the coefficients go to zero.

Now, let's proof your's statement. Notice that:
$$
\|x \|^2 \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |c_n|^2
$$
And this implies that $|c_n|^2$ tends to zero, so does $|c_n|$.
This inequality is true because of the following equality:
$$
\| x\|^2 - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |c_n|^2 = \|x - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n e_n \|^2 \geq 0
$$

Comment: This part was always my problem "...And this implies that $|_|^2$ tends to zero, so does $|_|$..." I am not seeing it. To me this is not true unless $x$ tends to $0$

Comment: I guess that NeoFanatic is referring to the following statement: if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ converges to zero when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Also, to *feel* the statement, and stop thinking about *$|c_n|$ goes to 0 only when $x$ goes to zero*, you can think about $x = c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2=c_1e_1 + c_2e_2 + 0e_3 + 0e_4 + 0 e_5 \ldots$, hope this will help

Comment: shouldn't it be "...And this implies that $||x||^2$ tends to zero, so does $|_|$..."?

Comment: No, the norm  $\|x\|^2 < \infty$ is some constant, and by the inequality we get that the series converge, and every series which converge have coefficients which tend to zero

Comment: @NeoFanatic it seems that $||x||$ is finite in your last comment. But couldn't it be infinite? Or maybe couldn't we have $c_{\infty}=2$ ? $x=0e_1+0e_2+...2e_{\infty}$

Comment: We don't  have elements of infinite norm, and what is $c_{\infty}$?We have infinitly many coefficients, but every coefficient has finite index

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes total sense.